Hi I am getting "Multiple Definitions of","First defined here" error
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here: I have 3 .cpp files: main_program.cpp, read_input_data.cpp, write_output_data.cpp.
main program calls both, readinputdata reads in a string, and writeoutputdata writes it out. Data is being read into the string garbage which is defined in the namespace "INPUTDATA" present in INPUT.h, while the functions are declared in "FUNCTIONS.h".
This is the error I get:
g++ -o f2d ../obj/main_program.o ../obj/read_input_data.o ../obj/write_output_data.o -Wall -Wextra -O3 -Werror -pedantic -Ofast
/usr/bin/ld: ../obj/read_input_data.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `INPUTDATA::garbage[abi:cxx11]'; ../obj/main_program.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: ../obj/write_output_data.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `INPUTDATA::garbage[abi:cxx11]'; ../obj/main_program.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:20: f2d] Error 1

This is what my files look like:
main_program.cpp
// main_program.cpp
// libraries to include
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> //Wheres Wallace????
// header files
#include "../headers/INPUT.h"
#include "../headers/FUNCTIONS.h"

using namespace INPUTDATA;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    read_input_data();
    write_output_data();
    return 0;
}

read_input_data.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //Wheres Wallace????
#include "../headers/INPUT.h"
#include "../headers/FUNCTIONS.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace INPUTDATA;

void read_input_data()
{
    cin>>garbage;
}

write_output_data.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //Wheres Wallace????
#include "../headers/INPUT.h"
#include "../headers/FUNCTIONS.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace INPUTDATA;

void write_output_data()
{
    cout<<garbage<<endl;
}

INPUT.h
#ifndef INPUT_H // include guard
#define INPUT_H
#pragma once
#include <string> //Wheres Wallace????
using namespace std;
namespace INPUTDATA
{
    string garbage;
}
#endif

FUNCTIONS.h
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H // include guard
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#pragma once
void read_input_data();
void write_output_data();

#endif

And this is my makefile, but I don't think its the makefile because I tested a separate code using it as well:
IDIR =../headers
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O3 -Werror -pedantic -Ofast

HDIR=../headers
DEPSNAME = INPUT.h FUNCTIONS.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(HDIR)/%,$(DEPSNAME))

ODIR=../obj
OBJNAME = main_program.o read_input_data.o write_output_data.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(OBJNAME))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: f2d

f2d: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f f2d $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~ 

I really don't know what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can please help, I will be grateful. Thanks!
I am expecting that the error does not occur.

It should answer it, as INPUT.h is included from both read_input_data.cpp and write_input_data.cpp. It defines the string INPUTDATA::garbage.

In addition to the problem of multiple definitions, it is bad practice to employ using namespace std in a header file.   There are plenty of explanations available online (and in Q&As here) for that.     If you want to use std::string in a header, use its full name (std::string) rather than using namespace std and referring to it as string.   The (potential) benefit of reduced typing is not worth the disadvantages.

Be absolutely certain that inline variables really do what you want done before you move on to my next recommendation: Do not answer your question in the question. The only thing that belongs in a Stack Overflow Question is a single question. No answers. Instead write a formal Answer, and when allowed, select your answer as the answer.

garbage is a global variable that is defined in a header file. Each different .cpp file is called a compilation unit, because they are compiled separatedly. Once a compilation unit is compiled, it creates an object file (each .o file).
Consider that when you include a file, from the point of view of the compiler, this is like if the contents of the included file were "copy-pasted" in the .cpp file. This works recursively, so if you include a file that includes a second file, and so on, all the contents of all the recursively included files form part of the same compilation unit. If the same set of files is also included from other compilation units, the same contents will be compiled multiple times over and over again.
Since all of your translation units (aka .cpp files) include INPUT.h, the compiler will define the global variable garbage multiple times in each .o generated, and so all of your .o files will have its own "copy" of the garbage global variable.
So you are claiming to the compiler that you are defining a global (and thus single) variable called garbage, but that variable ends up being defined multiple times, which violates the one-definition rule (ODR), because there must only be only one definition of a same entity (the global, but same applies to functions). This is detected by the linker (in the f2d rule of your makefile), which is the software that tries to merge all .o in a single executable.
Write extern in front of string garbage like this in INPUT.h:
namespace INPUTDATA
{
    extern string garbage;
}

That way you explicitely declare to the compiler that garbage is not going to be define "in this compilation unit", but in some "external" place, still allowing the compiler to know the variable exists. Now, together with the above, create INPUT.cpp with:
#include "INPUT.h"

namespace INPUTDATA
{
    string garbage;
}

and you are done.

Hi, I created this file:
`#include "../headers/INPUT.h"
#include  //Wheres Wallace????
using namespace std;
namespace INPUTDATA
{
string garbage;
}`
But its still not working

@SahajJain and you have to specify extern in frony of string garbage in the INPUT.h file.
